# Template for Button with an appended toggleButton (ToggleButton shows context menu on clicking)

Tags: wpf, button, combobox, controltemplate, togglebutton

How to make a control which has both button and togglebutton/Combobox? on clicking the toggle button i should be able fire a command depends on the selection.
1. I want some templates to achieve this (i.e. On clicking left side of the control, i have to fire Open command and on selecting right side of the control it should open other options ).
2. Also, is there any way to achieve such that i just have to provide various items like "Open", "Show previous versions" and the button takes the first item (in this case "Open")

Comment: Google "SplitButton WPF" and you will find what you need.

Comment: Here is the link: [Extended WPF Toolkit SplitButton](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SplitButton&referringTitle=Documentation).